# Duda sobre signal y slots en QT

Tags: qt

Hola estoy empezando a programar QT con el objetivo de aprender lo máximo posible pero tengo una cuestión. Se que con una señal puedes conectarlas a muchos slots. (Ejemplo multiples acciones o desplazar diferentes progress bar). Pero lo que no se es cuando uno de esos slots esta ocupado que pasa con el resto de slots? Y si por ejemplo he cometido por error un bucle infinito y la señal nunca termina que pasa con las demas señales? Esque soy principiante y quiero aprender la máxima teoría posible. Perdonar si me explicado mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt es multihilo, sin embargo, por defecto, la ejecución de una señal se va a ejecutar en un único hilo (Es como está programado el bucle de ejecución). Esto implica que los diferentes slots se van a ejecutar de forma secuencial.

Debido a esto, si la ejecución se queda atascada en un slot por un bucle infinito, una espera activa, una tarea costosa, etc. Los slots posteriores no se ejecutarán, o al menos no hasta que la ejecución abandone el slot problemático.

Un saludo

Comment: y si una señal se atasca que pasa con el resto de señales? cuando se utiliza diferentes objetos se puede evitar esto?

Comment: QT es multihilo porque tiene mecanismos para ejecutar múltiples hilos. Pero la ejecución por defecto es monohilo. Esto quiere decir que si la ejecución se atasca tu aplicación se quedará congelada

Comment: Qt es demasiado extenso como para describirlo de forma precisa en una sola pregunta